# How to edit a file in IsolatedStorage C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have been fiddling with this problem for the past hour so I thought you guys may be able to help on a Friday afternoon!

### Problem

---

I am trying to edit an XML file in localstorage but can't figure out how to edit the existing file and re-save the file. The edit I have made it to remove a certain node from the XML.

### Code

---

Here is the method that does all the work.

This first code snippet was already in the code and basically creates the XML file and saves it to localstorage.:

```
protected byte[] CreateFileData(PortableBusinessObjects.Location location, string geoObjectFilename)
{
    byte[] fileData = null;
    var xmlFile = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(geoObjectFilename) + ".xml";
    var zipFile = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(geoObjectFilename) + ".zip";  

    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = localStorage.CreateFile(xmlFile))
    {
                XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(fileStream);
                if (location.GetType() == typeof(PortableBusinessObjects.Shape))
                    _xmlShapeSerializer.Serialize(writer, location);
                else if (location.GetType() == typeof(PortableBusinessObjects.Point))
                    _xmlPointSerializer.Serialize(writer, location);
                fileStream.Flush();
                fileStream.Close();
    }                 
}
```

This is my attempt at overwriting the saved file (Doesn't work):

```
using (IsolatedStorageFileStream doc = localStorage.OpenFile(xmlFile, FileMode.Open))
{

    System.Xml.Linq.XDocument test = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(doc);
    test.Descendants("Time").Remove();

     XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(doc);


     doc.Flush();
     doc.Close();
}
```

### Question

---

Where do I place my code that removes the "Time" nodes and saves the file?

Comment: Use the save method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/cc838476(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your saving code doesn't do any saving - you just create an `XmlWriter` and do nothing with it.

There are various methods built into `XDocument` than can help you here.  While you could pass your `XmlWriter` to it, you can actually save directly to the stream:

```
test.Save(doc);
```

Note you will need to move to the beginning of the stream before writing to it - loading your XML will have read to the end:

```
doc.Position = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `IsolatedStorageFileStream` together with the  `StreamWriter`.
See [How to: Read and Write to Files in Isolated Storage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xf96a1wz(v=vs.110).aspx)
With `XDocument` you then have to Save() the new contents to the stream.